# possible to count list of dict easily?

Tags: python, list, count

I have a list of dict like this:

```
def shCounter(orderList):
    try:
        orderCountList=[]
        orderList = [{'key': '130690 002_11', 'sku': '130690 002', 'size': '11', 'name': "Air Jordan 12 Retro 'Flu Game' 2016"}, {'key': '575441 030_6.5', 'sku': '575441 030', 'size': '6.5', 'name': "Air Jordan 1 Retro High OG GS 'Pine Green 2.0'",}, {'key': '575441 030_6.5', 'sku': '575441 030', 'size': '6.5', 'name': "Air Jordan 1 Retro High OG GS 'Pine Green 2.0'"}, {'key': '575441 030_7', 'sku': '575441 030', 'size': '7', 'name': "Air Jordan 1 Retro High OG GS 'Pine Green 2.0'"}, {'key': '575441 030_7', 'sku': '575441 030', 'size': '7', 'name': "Air Jordan 1 Retro High OG GS 'Pine Green 2.0'"}, {'key': '575441 030_7', 'sku': '575441 030', 'size': '7', 'name': "Air Jordan 1 Retro High OG GS 'Pine Green 2.0'"}, {'key': 'FW5190_6.5', 'sku': 'FW5190', 'size': '6.5', 'name': "Yeezy Boost 350 V2 'Yecheil Non-Reflective'"}, {'key': 'FW5190_6.5', 'sku': 'FW5190', 'size': '6.5', 'name': "Yeezy Boost 350 V2 'Yecheil Non-Reflective'"}]
        #print(orderList)
        for order in orderList:
            print(order["key"])
            orderCountList.append(order["key"])
            orderCountList.append(order["sku"])
            orderCountList.append(order["size"])
        print(orderCountList)
        orderCount={}
        for order in orderList:
            print(orderCountList.count(order["size"])
            #orderCount[order["key"]]
```

iI want to count all product by sku & size, I found a function "count". however, I cannot count the dict directly. Also, I tried change it to list, it just counts either total number of same sku, or size.

How can I count it by sku by size?

My expected output is like this:

```
product A:  

6.5 : 2,
7 : 5,
8 : 1,
total : 8

product B: 

7 : 1,
9 : 2,
Total : 3
```

Comment: how did you differentiate product A and product B?

Comment: product A and product B define by sku, thanks

Comment: `orderList`  didn't contain 'size:9' but in your expected output contains 'size:9' can you clarify this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possibility is to have a dict of the sizes for each given item, and update the occurences for each item in the orderList. Like this:

```
orderCounts = {}
for item in orderList:
    sku = item["sku"]
    if not sku in orderCounts:
         orderCounts[sku] = {}
    size = item["size"]
    if not size in orderCounts[sku]:
         orderCounts[sku][size] = 0
    orderCounts[sku][size] += 1
```